# Dict into Dict Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new in Python, Currently I am working data dictionary.
I expect to create dict into dict like this:

```
dates = {201101:{perf:10, reli:20, qos:300}, 201102:{perf:40, reli:0, qos:30}}
```

I already have the keys, and I have to created default values for initialization. i.e:

`{201101:{perf:0, reli:0}, 201102:{perf:0, reli:0}}`

how to do initiation and update the specifict dict. ie dates[201101[perf]] = 10.
Thanks!

Comment: What is `201101{perf=10, reli=20, qos=300}`

Comment: @thefourtheye sorry my mistake on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with

```
dates = {201101{perf=10, reli=20, qos=300}, 201102{perf=40, reli=0, qos=30}}
```

is not a valid python dict. This is:

```
dates = {201101: {'perf':10, 'reli':20, 'qos':300}, 201102:{'perf':40, 'reli':0, 'qos':30}}
```

Once you have initiated the dict of dict as:

```
dates = {201101:{'perf':0, 'reli':0}, 201102:{'perf':0, 'reli':0}}
```

you update it by doing:

```
dates[201101]['perf'] = 10
```

Demo:

```
>>> dates = {201101:{'perf':0, 'reli':0}, 201102:{'perf':0, 'reli':0}}
>>> dates[201101]['perf'] = 10
>>> dates
{201101: {'reli': 0, 'perf': 10}, 201102: {'reli': 0, 'perf': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to separate keys from their values with a `:`. Secondly, your keys need to be strings or numbers. Example.

```
dates = { 201101: {'perf': 10, 'reli':20, 'qos': 300} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first dict:

```
dates={201101:{'perf':0, 'reli':0}, 201102:{'perf':0, 'reli':0}}
```

One way to update key's value:

```
date[201101]={'perf': 10, 'reli':20, 'qos': 300}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Method that you would need in case of run-time values is setdefault(i,[]) or {} instead of []. This allows you to dynamically create nested dictionaries instead of "flat".

For example:

```
    dict = {}
    for i in range(0,10):
        dict.setdefault(i,{})
        # Only now you can use the nested dict of level 1
        for j in range(0,10):
            dict[i][j] = j
```

This is just an example, you can dynamically create dict of any deep and with heterogeneous elements as list or other dict.